# How do I create android recycler-view with given image, help appreciated

Tags: android, android-recyclerview, layout-manager

[image: demo]

looking to create recycler-view / list-view in android java/kotlin.

Comment: Are we supposed to write one for you? what have you tried so far?

Comment: @JustSightseeing any available library or code sample will help alot

Answer (score 0):

Try [this](https://github.com/vishnus1224/RotaryDialerView) library. it does have similar functionality but, you'll have to modify it according to your needs of course.